# how much baking soda and vinegar will you need to fully fill a ziplock bag up without popping it?

Tags: gas-laws, stoichiometry, home-experiment

EXACTLY how much baking soda and vinegar will you need to FULLY fill a ziplock bag up without popping it or it being deflated?

I am really confused. That is all our teacher told us and he said that we need to be prepared with a procedure for a lab. I know it deals with stoichiometry but don't know where to go from there. We know we can find the volume of the bag by filling it with water and emptying the water into a beaker.

WHAT DO I DO NEXT? help greatly appreciated!

The Ziploc bag is 1 quart.

I got this formula-
HC2H3O2+NaHCO3------>NaC2H3O2+H20+CO2

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: There is too little information ,as we do not know the endurance of the bag. Hmm, I see 1 Quart = cca 0.946 L.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the water doesn't displace much volume in the bag, the volume a mole of CO2 displaces at room temperatre is 22 L.

pV=nRT

p=1 atm

T=298 K

R=0.0821 $\frac{L*atm}{mol K}$

Step 1: find out how much volume the bag is in liters (units need to be consistent)

Step 2: Using pV=nRT solve for the number of moles using that volume of CO2 that you need

Step 3: The ratio of CO2 to acetic acid (HC2H3O2) and sodium bicarbonate (NaHCO3) is 1 so you need that many moles of each

Step 4: Convert moles of HC2H3O2 and NaHCO3 to mass using their molar masses